# Delphi Component Development - Propagate Events inside component

Tags: delphi, event-handling, custom-component

I am trying to develop a new TEdit-Component.

```
TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
```

The component is meant to Filter an associated DataSet based on the string that is entered in its Edit-Field.

this is what my component looks like:

```
type
TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    fFilter:String;
    fDataSource:TDataSource;
    fDataSet:TDataSet;
    fText:string;
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
    procedure SetFilter(value:String);
    procedure SetDS(value:TDataSource);
    procedure FilterRecords(DataSet:TDataSet; var Accept:Boolean);
    procedure Change(Sender:TObject);
    procedure SetText(value:String);
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);
  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }
    property Text:String read fText write SetText;
    property Filter:String read fFilter write SetFilter;
    property DataSource:TDataSource read fDataSource write SetDS;
  end;
```

Now, I am pretty Novice when it comes to component-development. My first Idea was to Override the OnFilterRecord-method of the Dataset as soon as the DataSource gets assigned to my component and trigger it whenever the text of my Edit-component changes.

```
procedure TDBFilterEdit.SetDS(value:TDataSource);
var
  myaccept:Boolean;
begin
  fDataSource:=value;
  fDataSet:=fDataSource.DataSet;
  if fDataSet=nil then Exit;

  fDataSet.OnFilterRecord:=FilterRecords;
  if Filter<>'' then fDataSet.OnFilterRecord(fDataSet,myaccept);
end;
```

My Problem is, I don't know how to make the component aware that its Text-property got updated. I tried overriding the OnChange-Method with following code

```
procedure TDBFilterEdit.Change(Sender:TObject);
begin
  Filter:=Text;
  inherited Change();
end;
```

however, to no avail so far.

Comment: The usual way of doing this is to write a method (that might be called DoOnChange) that's called within your Change and does whatever you want, including invoking any special event handlers that you might want to provide.  Have a look at the various DoOnxxxx methods in the VCL and you should soon get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Problem is, I don't know how to make the component aware that its Text-property got updated.

The `Text` property is inherited from `TControl`.  When the property value changes, `TControl` issues a `CM_TEXTCHANGED` notification message to itself.  Descendant classes can handle that message by either:

1. using a `message` handler:

   ```
   type
     TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
       ...
       procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
       ...
     published
       ...
       // DO NOT redeclare the Text property here!
       // It is already published by TEdit...
     end;

   procedure TDBFilterEdit.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     inherited;
     // use new Text value as needed...
     Filter := Text;
   end;
   ```
2. overriding the virtual `WndProc()` method.

   ```
   type
     TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
       ...
     protected
       ...
       procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
       ...
     end;

   procedure TDBFilterEdit.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     inherited;
     if Message.Msg = CM_TEXTCHANGED then
     begin
       // use new Text value as needed...
       Filter := Text;
     end;
   end;
   ```

As for the rest of your component, it should look more like this:

```
type
  TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
    fDataSource: TDataSource;
    fDataSet: TDataSet;
    fFilter: String;
    procedure FilterRecords(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
    procedure SetDataSource(Value: TDataSource);
    procedure SetDataSet(Value: TDataSet);
    procedure SetFilter(const Value: String);
    procedure StateChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure UpdateDataSetFilter;
  protected
    { Protected-Deklarationen }
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published-Deklarationen }
    property DataSource: TDataSource read fDataSource write SetDataSource;
    property Filter: String read fFilter write SetFilter;
  end;

...

destructor TDBFilterEdit.Destroy;
begin
  SetDataSource(nil);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.FilterRecords(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  // ...
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if Operation = opRemove then
  begin
    if AComponent = fDataSource then
    begin
      SetDataSet(nil);
      fDataSource := nil;
    end
    else if AComponent = fDataSet then
    begin
      fDataSet := nil;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.SetFilter(const Value: String);
begin
  if fFilter <> Value then
  begin
    fFilter := Value;
    UpdateDataSetFilter;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.SetDataSource(Value: TDataSource);
begin
  if fDataSource <> Value then
  begin
    SetDataSet(nil);

    if fDataSource <> nil then
    begin
      fDataSource.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
      fDataSource.OnStateChange := nil;
    end;

    fDataSource := Value;    

    if fDataSource <> nil then
    begin
      fDataSource.FreeNotification(Self);
      fDataSource.OnStateChange := StateChanged;
      SetDataSet(fDataSource.DataSet);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.SetDataSet(Value: TDataSet);
begin
  if fDataSet <> Value then
  begin
    if fDataSet <> nil then
    begin
      fDataSet.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
      fDataSet.OnFilterRecord := nil;
    end;

    fDataSet := Value;

    if fDataSet <> nil then
    begin
      fDataSet.FreeNotification(Self);
      fDataSet.OnFilterRecord := FilterRecords;
      UpdateDataSetFilter;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.StateChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fDataSource.DataSet <> fDataSet then
    SetDataSet(fDataSource.DataSet);
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.UpdateDataSetFilter;
begin
  if fDataSet <> nil then
  begin
    fDataSet.Filter := fFilter;
    fDataSet.Filtered := fFilter <> '';
  end;
end;

procedure TDBFilterEdit.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.Msg = CM_TEXTCHANGED then
    Filter := Text;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: sorry, my bad.  The `CM_TEXTCHANGED` message is only sent when the `Text` property is updated programmably in code.  To detect when the *user* changed the text, you need to handle the Win32 [`EN_CHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676.aspx) notification instead:

1. using a `message` handler:

   ```
   type
     TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
       ...
       procedure CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_TEXTCHANGED;
       procedure CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
       ...
     published
       ...
       // DO NOT redeclare the Text property here!
       // It is already published by TEdit...
     end;

   procedure TDBFilterEdit.CMTextChanged(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     inherited;
     // use new Text value as needed...
     Filter := Text;
   end;

   procedure TDBFilterEdit.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
   begin
     inherited;
     if Message.NotifyCode = EN_CHANGE then
     begin
       // use new Text value as needed...
       Filter := Text;
     end;
   end;
   ```
2. overriding the virtual `WndProc()` method.

   ```
   type
     TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
       ...
     protected
       ...
       procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
       ...
     end;

   procedure TDBFilterEdit.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     inherited;
     case Message.Msg of
       CM_TEXTCHANGED: begin
         // use new Text value as needed...
         Filter := Text;
       end;
       CN_COMMAND: begin
         if TWMCommand(Message).NotifyCode = EN_CHANGE then
         begin
           // use new Text value as needed...
           Filter := Text;
         end;
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ```

In fact, `TCustomEdit` already handles `EN_CHANGE` for you, and will call its virtual `Change()` method (to fire its `OnChange` event), which you can override:

```
    type
      TDBFilterEdit = class(TEdit)
        ...
      protected
        ...
        procedure Change; override;
        ...
      end;

    procedure TDBFilterEdit.Change;
    begin
      inherited;
      // use new Text value as needed...
      Filter := Text;
    end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me get further to my goal.

I chose method 1 and made a CMTextChanged-message-Handler,
however it won't fire.

I tried a CM_MOUSEENTER-message Handler, which DID fire though, but the Text property remained empty.

Do I need to implement/override the other procedures like Notification, StateChange and WndProc?

Also, assigning the Datasource works, but for some strange reason, the DataSet of my DataSource remains nil

Comment: I found out that the correct message-handler I'm looking for is CN_COMMAND, now I can get the procedure to fire for the first letter I enter into the edit-field.

any idea how to invoke this on every button press?

Comment: I figured it out, the dataset only executes the OnFilterRecord when it switches from filtered:=false to filtered:=true.

since I didn't reset the filtered-property anywhere, it's value was always true after I entered the first letter into my edit-field.

now the component behaves almost as intended, all that is left is researching the mysterious behaviour of the "nil-Dataset" when assigning the Datasource (maybe I'll just use a Dataset directly instead of a datasource) and extensive testing of my FilterRecords-method.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about forgetting the `EN_CHANGE` notification.  I have updated my answer.